# Is there a way to overcome authentication pop-up when load testing with LoadStorm

Tags: load

I want to do the stress and load testing in the staging environment of a web site, but it has an authentication popup when the URL loads and I don't know how to pass this login step in load storm.

**Steps followed:**

1. Add new scenario in LoadStorm
2. Add new step: Open a page
3. URL:/ , Server: staging.site.com. Server is "Verified"
4. Click [Save]

**Actual Result:**

`Status:` "You have failed to logon" because authentication is required in a popup."

**Note:**

I have tried adding server: user:pass@staging.site.com but it did not pass Verification step. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with Load Strom, but I believe there are several ways to circumvent this issue if you are the owner of the website (which I assume you are)

1.try editing the pupop to already include the credentials so you would only have to record pressing "enter" without providing the actual credentials.

1. a bit obvious, but you could try to edit the logon screen to be included outside of a pop-up.